# sympy : h**2+x**2--> x**2 + h**2 I want

Tags: sympy

Converted a polynomial to a string.

Is there a way to retrieve the first argument of Poly?

```
from sympy import *
import re
var('x h')
myPoly=h**2+x**2
print("#",myPoly)
print("#",re.findall('\(.*x',str(Poly(myPoly,x)))[0].lstrip("(").rstrip(", x"))
myPoly=h**2+3*h*x +3*x**2
print("#",myPoly)
print("#",re.findall('\(.*x',str(Poly(myPoly,x)))[0].lstrip("(").rstrip(", x"))
# h**2 + x**2
# x**2 + h**2
# h**2 + 3*h*x + 3*x**2
# 3*x**2 + 3*h*x + h**2
```

i try myPoly.args(20220715)
http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/SymPy.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/_modules/sympy/polys/polytools.html

def args(self):

```
from sympy import *
import re
var('x h')
myPoly=h**2+x**2
print("#",myPoly)
print("#",myPoly.args)
print("#",Poly(myPoly,x).args)
myPoly=h**2+3*h*x +3*x**2
print("#",myPoly)
print("#",myPoly.args)
print("#",Poly(myPoly,x).args)
# h**2 + x**2
# (h**2, x**2)
# (h**2 + x**2, x)
# h**2 + 3*h*x + 3*x**2
# (h**2, 3*x**2, 3*h*x)
# (h**2 + 3*h*x + 3*x**2, x)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify would you would like to achieve?

Comment: Why don't you just look at the expression's own structure, e.g. `myPoly.args`?